# win32com in Python Spyder console results in an error

Tags: python, excel, winapi, anaconda, spyder

I'm just running the following code, straight from [this documentation/tutorial](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/).

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
wb.SaveAs('add_a_workbook.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

And got this:

```
  execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/script.py", line 106, in <module>
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\2.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Workbooks.py", line 34, in Add
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(181, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((12, 17),),Template
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Does anyone have any idea why? I've tried using an xlsx vs. xls file, and changing the file address, and trying multiple examples from that tutorial, and they all give me similar errors, and I have no idea why.

I can get as far as `wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()` before I get the `TypeError: an integer is required` warning, and if I try  `wb = excel.Workbooks.Add`, it will run and I won't get the error, but I can't do anything from there on.

Does anyone know what this is? Thanks in advance.

[Edit:]

I tried a word file for comparison and I works fine.

Does anyone know why one of these works and one doesn't?

```
word = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
word.Documents.Open('C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.docx')

excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\username\Desktop\output.xlsx')
```

[Edit 2:]

Okay, I found the problem is with the Spyder IDE. If I write the same code in Anaconda, it'll work fine. Does anyone know why Anaconda works but Sypder doesn't? I checked the system paths and they're identical, and even trying to execute a .py program in Anaconda doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. If you use `excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')` can you use `wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()`? For some reason there is something interfering with win32com's `gen_py`. Do you have same platform for both Office and Python (say, 64 bit in both cases)?

Comment: No, I get the same error `ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(181, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((12, 17),),Template` `TypeError: an integer is required`, and yes, both are 64 bit. If it helps, for some reason I started getting a new error, I included `import pythoncom` 
`pythoncom.CoInitialize()` and the error went away and it successfully ran. Then when I re-ran it I got the old typeerror error back...

Comment: The problem was with the Spyder IDE.

Comment: I think you should reword the question to be specifically about how it works in anaconda but not spyder IDE. Perhaps Spyder uses its own copy of Python interpreter, 32 bit? Try printing the version string from script when run in anaconda vs spyder.

Comment: Okay, reworded the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to be the only person on the internet with this problem, but my workaround was I used a different spyder python interpretter.

`Python interpreter` gave me all sorts of errors doing pretty much every win32com excel command, but `IPython console` works fine. No idea why.

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) They work very differently internally. In some cases the Python console can do the job better, and in others IPython is the one to select. However, the IPython console has more features and in general is better tested (because IPython has much more users).

Comment: Nice idea changing consoles. I just started getting this error (two months ago it wasn't there). However, I did the other way around, going from an IPython console to a Python one, and it worked.